# Is Bash support Unicode 6.0?

Tags: bash, unicode

When I use unicode 6.0 character(for example, 'beer mug') in Bash(4.3.11), it doesn't display correctly.

Just copy and paste character is okay, but if you use utf-16 hex code like

`$ echo -e '\ud83c\udf7a'`,

output is '??????'.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use UTF-16 with bash and a unix(-like) terminal. Bash strings are strings of bytes, and the terminal will (if you have it configured correctly) be expecting UTF-8 sequences. In UTF-8, surrogate pairs are illegal. So if you want to show your beer mug, you need to provide the UTF-8 sequence.

Note that `echo -e` interprets unicode escapes in the forms `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX`, producing the corresponding UTF-8 sequence. So you can get your beer mug (assuming your terminal font includes it) with:

```
echo -e '\U0001f37a'
```